# @WebFilter vs. <Filter> in web.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations, servlet-filters

I wonder how I can achieve a behaviour like using this @WebFilter annotation

```
@WebFilter(
    urlPatterns = "/*",
    filterName = "AuthenticationFilter",
    description = "Filter all URLs"
    ,
    initParams = {
@WebInitParam(name = "unprotectedUrls", value = "/,/login,/authentication,/notification,/sdr")})
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
...}
```

(which works well, meaning that I don't have to be logged in only for the listed paths but for all other paths I have to be)...
by using a <filter> element in web.xml.

Using this filter in web.xml:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.foo.bar.helper.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>unprotectedUrls</param-name>
        <param-value>/,/login,/authentication,/notification,/sdr</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
```

it is not recognized which means that I don't have to be logged in for all paths/URLs. No filtering takes place.

My intention is to make the init-params configurable so that I don't have to edit the code/class whenever a further URL shall be included or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have defined the filter, you have not mapped the filter. NExt to the `filter` element you also need a `filter-mapping` element to map the filter to urls, this is basically the replacement for the `urlPatterns` attribute of the `@WebFilter`

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name> AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: :)) 
Yes, indeed. I found out this in the meantime but I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question within 10 hours after asking. 
However, thank you.

Comment: So with the following annotation @WebFilter("/*") we can do without the web.xml markup altogether ?